# Is there a way to zip a folder of files into one zip, gzip, bzip, etc file using Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, bzip2

**My Goal**: I have hundreds of Google Cloud Storage folders with hundreds of images in them. I need to be able to zip them up and email a user a link to a single zip file.

I made an attempt to zip these files on an external server using PHP's zip function, but that has proved to be fruitless given the ultimate size of the zip files I'm creating.

I have since found that Google Cloud offers a Bulk Compress Cloud Storage Files utility (docs are at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-utilities#api). I was able to successfully call this utility, but for zips each file into it's own bzip or gzip file.

For instance, if I had the following files in the folder I'm attempt to zip:

- apple.jpg
- banana.jpg
- carrot.jpg

The resulting outputDirectory would have:

- apple.bzip2
- banana.bzip2
- carrot.bzip2

Ultimately, I'm hoping to create a single file named *fruits.bzip2* that can be unzipped to reveal these three files.

Here's an example of the request parameters I'm making to https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/PROJECT_ID/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Bulk_Compress_GCS_Files

```
{
  "jobName": "ziptest15",
  "environment": {
    "zone": "us-central1-a"
  },
  "parameters": {
    "inputFilePattern": "gs://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/testing/samplefolder1a/*.jpg",
    "outputDirectory": "gs://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/testing/zippedfiles/",
    "outputFailureFile": "gs://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/testing/zippedfiles/failure.csv",
    "compression": "BZIP2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the max size of your folder to compress?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I'm using a Google Cloud Storage folder and I don't see a limit on how large the contents of the folder can be anywhere. But I have folders that are filled with several GBs of images and there doesn't seem to be stopping me from adding more to them.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve that is to create an app that:

- Download locally all the file of a GCS prefix (that you name "directory" but directory doesn't exist on GCS, only file with the same prefix)
- Create an archive (can be a ZIP or a TAR. ZIP won't really compress the image. The image format is already a compressed format. You especially want only one 1 with all the image in it)
- Upload the archive to GCS
- Clean the files

---

Now you have to choose where to run this app.

- On Cloud Run, you are limited by the space that you have in memory (for now, new feature are coming). For now you are limited to 8Gb of memory (and soon 16Gb), your app will be able to process total image size of 45% of the memory capacity (45% for the image size, 45% for the archive size, 10% for the app memory footprint.). Set the concurrency parameter to 1.
- If you need more space, you can use Compute Engine.

  - Set up a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) that run your script and stop automatically the VM at the end. The script read the parameter from the metadata server and run your app with the correct parameters
  - Before each run, update the [Compute Engine metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) with the directory to process (and maybe other app parameter
  - -> The issue is that you can only run 1 process at a time. Or you need to create a VM for each job, and then delete the VM at the end of the startup script instead of stopping the VM
- A side solution is to use Cloud Build. Run a Build with the parameters in the substitutions variables and perform the job in Cloud Build. You are limited to 10 builds in parallel. Use the [`diskSizeGb`](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config) build option to set the correct disk size according to your file size requirements.

---

The dataflow template only zip each file unitary, and don't create an archive.